# difference between global variable and window variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and I am unable to understand difference between global variable and window variable and in which namespace the variables will be stored

For example,

```
var a = 1;
alert(window.a);
```

This will create alert window with message '1'.

```
let b = 1;
alert(window.b);
```

This will create alert window with message 'undefined'.

But if b is not getting created in window space, where it is getting created. When we run a javascript program, will 2 namespaces be created (one for global and one for window)?

Comment: The `let` keyword declares a variable within block-scope.

Comment: you are absolutely right :)

Comment: "*will 2 namespaces be created (one for global and one for window)?*" - Yes. Although they are intertwined and a bit hard to distinguish.